# Why would running 32 bit executeable on 64 bit FreeBSD v8.1 give ELF error?

Tags: 32bit-64bit, porting, freebsd, elf

I have a 32 bit build on FreeBSD v8.1 and attempt to run it on a 64 bit FreeBSD v8.1 and it fails:

```
[si-fbsd8x64b ~] flume --version
ELF interpreter /libexec/ld-elf.so.1 not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Can this work, if so, what change do I need to make to enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install lib32 part of distribution.

ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/8.1-RELEASE/lib32/